# Определить какой из CheckBox был нажат (WPF C#)

Tags: c#

пишу небольшую программу на WPF и возникла необходимость значение CheckBox отправлять в БД

Есть ли способ в MVVM проверить, какой из CheckBox был нажат?

Хочу создать общий метод, который будет переключать значения разных проперти в зависимости от нажатого CheckBox

Не хочется на каждый вешать свою команду и отдельный метод)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если в лоб, то обработчик события Checked (или как-то так), если по-нормальному, то привязка к bool через Binding. Вопрос слишком абстрактный, нужно больше деталей. Что именно не получается?

Comment: 1. Не ленитесь, если это все разные настройки, разные объекты, то они должны иметь разные команды, обработчики, и так далее, которые уже потом вы можете свести к одному если надо. Так вы имеете больше контроля, чем все намешенное в одну кучу. 2. Для оповещения о том, что свойство изменено, существует `INotifyPropertChanged`, у которого есть событие `OnPropertyChanged` (или как-то так), которое содержит в сете свойство того, кто изменился. Это все значит, что вам достаточно привязать `CheckBox` к своим свойствами, которые вызывают INPC, подписаться на событие, готово.